# pullback of certain forms

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $p : W \rightarrow S$ be a smooth morphism of algebraic varieties over $\mathbb{C}$. Is it always true that:

$$p^*H^{p,n-p}(S)=p^*H^n(S,\mathbb{C})\cap H^{p,n-p}(W),$$

whenever $n\geq p$? If not, are there any more restrictive hypothesis under which it gets true?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is yes, and the morphism doesn't have to be smooth.

A fancy way to explain this
is that if $f:W\to S$ is a morphism of complex algebraic varieties, $f^*:H^n(S)\to H^n(W)$
is compatible with mixed Hodge structures (by Deligne), and the functor
$H\mapsto H^{pq}:= Gr^p_FGr_{p+q}^WH$ form MHS to vector spaces is exact

In the case that I suspect you actually care about  when $W$ and $S$ are both smooth and projective, there is an easier way to see this. In this case, there is canonical Hodge structure determined
by the Hodge filtration: $\alpha\in F^pH^n(S)$ if $\alpha$ is represented by a sum of
forms of type $(p',q')$ with $p'\ge p$. One recovers the usual bigrading by $H^{pq}(S)=F^p\cap \bar F^q H^n(S)$ and $f^*$ clearly preserves the bigrading.
So your desired statement follows by decomposing $f^*\alpha$ into $(p,q)$-type.